# Filtering table by price, not showing what id expect

Tags: php, postgresql

**The Problem**

I am having trouble filtering my table, I have filtered it for product category but I am unsure how to do it when looking at numbers.

**Expected Outcome**

What I expect to see when the user presses the submit button is for the table to change to what ever it was that submitted. For example, in the drop down box there is an option for 'Less than £1', this meaning a price range less than a pound. If I was to press this I would expect to see the table change, showing only products with a price less than 1 pound.

**Here is the code**

*Drop Down Menu*

```
<form action="database.php" method="post">
<select name="price" id="price">
    <option value="">All Products</option>
    <option value="1">Less than £1</option>
    <option value="2">More than £1, Less than £5</option>
    <option value="3">More than £5, Less than £10</option>
</select>
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

*Code regarding this in the table code*

```
if (!empty($_POST['price'])) {
    // Where conditional that will be used in the SQL query
    $where = " WHERE price = '".pg_escape_string($_POST['price'])."'";

    switch ($_POST['price']) {
        case 1: 
            $where = $where." and Price BETWEEN 0.00 AND 1.00";
            break;
        case 2: 
            $where = $where." and Price BETWEEN 1.00 AND 5.00";
            break;
        case 3: 
            $where = $where." and Price BETWEEN 5.00 AND 10.00";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**What happens when I press one of the options?**

For example, if I choose the 'Less than £1' option, then only products worth £1 are showing. If I choose the 'More than £1, Less than £5' option, then only products worth £2 are showing etc. I understand its because I have set the value to 1, 2, and 3. Is there a way round this?

Comment: Why you set: price = '".pg_escape_string($_POST['price'])."'" ? Delete it and it will work.

Comment: Because that's what I called the form, i thought i needed to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before, the switch statement you're setting $where to

```
$where = " WHERE price = '".pg_escape_string($_POST['price'])."'";
```

For talk take, this would make $where equal to

```
" WHERE price = '1'"
```

Then, in your switch you're ADDING onto the current where, if price is 1, $where ends up equal to

```
" WHERE price = '1' and Price BETWEEN 0.00 AND 1.00"
```

This creates a conflict, all you need to do is alter your code to remove the first thing you set $where equal to and amend your switch like so:

```
if (!empty($_POST['price'])) {

switch ($_POST['price']) {
        case 1: 
            $where = " WHERE price BETWEEN 0.00 AND 1.00";
            break;
        case 2: 
            $where = " WHERE price BETWEEN 1.00 AND 5.00";
            break;
        case 3: 
            $where = " WHERE price BETWEEN 5.00 AND 10.00";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you initialize your `WHERE` clause, you're setting up an exact match between the `price` column and the `value` from the drop-down, so you end up with something like

```
SELECT ...
  WHERE price = '2'
    AND price BETWEEN 1.00 AND 3.00...
```

Change your code to set `$where = 'WHERE 1 = 1 ';` to create an always-true base WHERE that you can safely extend, as in

```
SELECT ...
  WHERE 1 = 1
    AND price BETWEEN 1.00 AND 3.00...
```

Hope that helps.